# Change Linux console screen blanking behavior

Tags: linux, console, screensaver, framebuffer, virtual-terminal

How do I change the screen blanking behavior on Linux virtual terminals?

For example, if I switch to a VT from X, login, and leave the system alone for 5 minutes or so, the screen will blank like a screensaver.  It comes back with any keypress, like a screensaver.

Mostly I just want to change the timeout, but I'm also interested in other settings.

If it helps, one of my systems is running Ubuntu 10.04 with the stock graphics drivers.  `fbset` shows the console using the `radeondrmfb` framebuffer device.

Comment: Hope this helps you, I found this when I met the same question http://askubuntu.com/questions/138918/how-do-i-disable-the-blank-console-screensaver-on-ubuntu-server

Answer (score 53):

`setterm` from [@whitequark's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/152347/change-linux-console-screen-blanking-behavior/152349#152349) is a reasonable userspace tool, but it's not the whole story.

The default console blanking behavior is baked into the kernel at compile time.  It is configurable at boot time [with the paramater *consoleblank=*](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0906.0/00784.html), or in userspace with `setterm`.  From the kernel documentation ([The kernel's command-line parameters](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html)):

```
consoleblank=  [KNL] The console blank (screen saver) timeout in
               seconds. A value of 0 disables the blank timer.
               Defaults to 0.
```

Here are the options, their defaults on my Ubuntu system, and their spheres of influence:

- `setterm -blank [0-60]`; always reports 0 when queried; effective when run on a real VT; affects all real TTYs; not effective when run in screen sessions on a VT.
- `setterm -powerdown [0-60]`; always reports "3]" (??); doesn't seem to have any effect.  Ubuntu kernels don't enable [APM_DISPLAY_BLANK](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/APM_DISPLAY_BLANK.html), and this could be related.
- `consoleblank=N`; defaults to 600 (10 minutes); affects all real VTs; affects screen sessions in a VT; no way to set while running.

So my options for changing the default is one of the following:

1. Add `setterm -blank X` (X in minutes, 0 to disable) to a shell init file like *.bashrc*.
2. Add `setterm -blank X` to */etc/rc.local*.
3. Add `consoleblank=Y` (Y in seconds, 0 to disable) to the kernel commandline by adding it to the parameter lists in */etc/default/grub*, either *GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX* or *GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT*.  (Don't forget to `update-grub`.)

Comment: I'd like to note that `setterm -blank X` did not work for me from within _tmux_, but worked perfectly when I exited _tmux_ before running the command.

Comment: If you are using grub2 as a bootloader, you could add this kernel parameter in /etc/default/grub `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="consoleblank=0"` and then update your grub config with `grub[2]-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: `3]` for `setterm -powerdown` is only the half true: `setterm -powerdown 3 | hexdump -c` returns `033 [ 1 4 ; 3 ]`. Unsure what should interprete this escape sequence...

Comment: Depending on your distribution and where you want the change to take effect, some of these options may not work.  I found that setterm in rc.local works great for RHEL 5 and 6, but not 7.

Comment: What is the difference between `-blank` and `-powerdown`? Trying to turn off display (vs set brightness to 0).

Comment: Does setting `consoleblank=600` in `/etc/default/grub` and running `update-grub` turn off display or does it set display brightness to 0?

Comment: Since linux 4.12 the consoleblank default is 0, i.e. disabled: [tty: Disable default console blanking interval](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=a4199f5eb8096d63828f7333fa45650a7b0a99ed)

Answer (score 12):

Try `setterm -blank $minutes` (or pass 0 to disable); `-powersave` option may also be related. `setterm` has a plenty of other useful options, too.

If you want to set these attributes on system startup, consider writing an initscript. This is just a script placed in `/etc/init.d` directory. Let it be called `setterm`:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ "$1" == "start" ] || exit 0 # only initialize everything when called as /etc/init.d/setterm start
for term in /dev/tty[0-9]*; do # select all ttyNN, but skip ttyS*
    setterm -blank 0 >$term <$term
    setterm -powersave off >$term <$term
done
```

Then make it executable:

```
# chmod +x /etc/init.d/setterm
```

And finally, create the /etc/rcX.d symlinks (the Debian way):

```
# update-rc.d setterm defaults
```

(If you'll get tired of that behavior, do `# update-rc.d -f setterm remove`. Note that `-f` must be the first argument).

Comment: hrm.  seems useful for on-the-fly, tho it seems on my test Ubuntu system it's actually the `-powerdown` setting that's in effect.  what about setting an on-boot, system-wide default?  is running `setterm -blank X` or `setterm -powerdown Y` in */etc/rc.local* (or *~/.bashrc*) reasonable?

Comment: Yes, but only if `rc.local` actually works. (Recent `upstart` migration screwed up some things, through it apparently exists and works on my system.) Otherwise you should create an initscript. That's easy: in our case, it must initialize everything when passed `start` as first argument, and do nothing otherwise. I'll describe that in my answer.

Comment: the command `setterm -blank X >/dev/ttyN` doesn't seem to work, so i don't think the initscript concept will work.  ran across a boottime parameter tho and did some more research.  i seem to be wrong about `-powerdown` and `-powersave`; haven't fully tested but those aren't working on my system.  `setterm -blank X` works, only from a real VT, and affects all VTs, so running once via */etc/rc.local* is reasonable.  (Upstart doesn't take away *rc.local*, just the */etc/rcX.d* stuff.)

Comment: Ahem. Seems that `setterm` emits escape sequences on `stdout`, but checks TTY type with `stdin`: I just checked, and `setterm ... >/dev/ttyN </dev/ttyN` works as intended.

Comment: that makes sense, and it works (from a real TTY), but what's the point of using that syntax at all?  (1) still doesn't work from within *screen* (or potentially other PTYs), which is where specifying a /dev/ttyN would be useful; (2) setting one VT affects all, so no need for the initscript loop.

Comment: Very strange: I tested that command from an ssh session (don't have a keyboard attached to server anyway). upd: probably that's because I have a Debian system there. Usually Ubuntu and Debian don't differ much, but this is apparently the case.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is looking for another possible solution for Debian (possibly not Ubuntu):

In `/etc/kbd/config`, look for a setting called "BLANK_TIME":

```
# screen blanking timeout.  monitor remains on, but the screen is cleared to
# range: 0-60 min (0==never)  kernels I've looked at default to 10 minutes.
# (see linux/drivers/char/console.c)
BLANK_TIME=30
```

Change it to 0, this will disable it:

```
BLANK_TIME=0
```

Tested on Debian 6 and 7.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running a newer Ubuntu that uses upstart, you can use:

```
for file in /etc/init/tty*.conf; do tty="/dev/`basename $file .conf`"; echo "post-start exec setterm -blank 0 -powersave off >$tty <$tty" | sudo tee -a "$file"; done
```

A little explanation of what's going on here:

Newer Ubuntu versions use upstart for system startup.  With upstart, the Linux consoles are setup with config files stored within /etc/init.  The command above starts by iterating over each of those config files:

```
for file in /etc/init/tty*.conf;
```

The tty's upstart config file name in $file is used to build the name of the tty device:

```
tty="/dev/`basename $file .conf`";
```

An upstart "post-start" command is built that runs "setterm" to disable screen blanking and power saving after the tty has been started:

```
echo "post-start exec setterm -blank 0 -powersave off >$tty <$tty"
```

And finally that command is appended to the upstart config file:

```
| sudo tee -a "$file";
```

Answer (score 2):

On my systems (various releases of RedHat Enterprise Linux), I have found that different approaches are needed.

For my RHEL 5 and 6 systems, I am able to add the line

`/bin/setterm -blank 0 -powerdown 0 -powersave off`

to `/etc/rc.local`.  This disables the console screen blanking at system startup.

I found that this does not work on RHEL 7 systems.  On RHEL7, running setterm from rc.local causes an error to be generated:

`setterm: $TERM is not defined.`

The command works from an interactive shell, where $TERM is defined (as `linux`).  If I force setterm to use it:

`/bin/setterm -term linux -blank 0 -powerdown 0 -powersave off`

Then I get a different error:

`setterm: cannot (un)set powersave mode: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

Even though the same command works fine from an interactive session.  Setting the `consoleblank` kernel parameter worked.

On RHEL7, edit `/etc/default/grub` and append `consoleblank=0` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` parameter.  Then run `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` and reboot.

I haven't tried setting `consoleblank` on RHEL5 or 6.

Comment: RHEL7 uses systemd; rc.local is not connected to a terminal by default.  I think you can add `</dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1` or something to make it work

Answer (score 2):

### Linux Console Private CSI Sequences

To set `sleep mode/screensaver` entering time (where X is a time in minute; 0 = never):

(from serial console)

```
echo -e '\033[9;X]' > /dev/tty1
```

or (from framebuffer console)

```
echo -e '\033[9;X]'
```

or to set it at each boot, use `/etc/inittab`:

```
tty1::sysinit:echo -e '\033[9;X]'
```

refs:

- http://www.armadeus.org/wiki/index.php?title=Framebuffer#Tips
- man console_codes

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Linux Mint has their own driver for the AMD Ryzen video and it has a problem with blanking the video after a short time. After trying all the suggestions from the forum with no success, I noticed on the information that AMD uses Nvidia drivers, so I downloaded a Linux driver from Nvidia and installed it. The video works fine now.

Answer (score -2):

Adding `gnome-screensaver-command --exit` to my `.profile` file fixed this problem for me on Debian Linux (Wheezy).

Thought I would add this to help others who are pulling their hair out trying to stop screen-blanking.

A checkbox titled *"Dim screen to save power"* is malfunctioning.  Even unchecked, it will STILL blank the screen according to the selected inactivity time.

UPDATE: I actually needed `sleep 30 && /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command --exit &` to make it work properly.  The GNOME screensaver seems to start long after .profile has been processed.

Comment: This is about console screen blanking, not Gnome screensavers.