# How to disable monitor standby in console?

Tags: linux, vga

My computer automatically stops sending a video signal when I stop typing in my console for a while, regardless if any command is running for a long time (like `watch`).

My question is, how can I disable this "power management" and force Linux to keep sending a video signal via VGA (in case that matters)?

Edit:// The machine is not running an XSever. It's just the bare console.
The kernel version is 3.8.0-27-generic and it's a standard Ubuntu Server 13.04

Comment: Do you mean outside entirely of X, or do you mean when you are using a terminal window within an X session? The answer will be very different. (Also check to make sure it isn't the monitor itself powering off because it thinks the image is "dark enough" to not be useful. Doesn't sound likely if you're running something through e.g. watch, but might be worth double-checking regardless.) If you mean outside of X, please specify your kernel version (`uname -a` output should do nicely) and possibly distribution and distribution version (contents of `/etc/os-release` should do nicely).

Comment: I know this is an old question, but nevertheless - did you find a solution? It seems that this [question/answer](https://superuser.com/q/152347/238539) explains what is going on and how to fix it.

Comment: @VL-80 Honestlyy, I wish I knew. This was 9 years ago. I don't even remember what I ate for dinner last week.

Answer (score 5):

To turn off VESA power saving, use the setterm command

```
setterm -blank 0 -powersave off -powerdown 0
xset s off
```

[Resource](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-disable-screen-blanking-screen-going-blank.html)

Comment: Sorry, but I am not running an XServer

Comment: Good point, Nikolays answer is better then.

Comment: @Nikolay Such a simple comment can cause us both to doubt our own answers.

Comment: @Nikolay Correct. xset and xterm - as the name suggests - require X

Comment: Sorry, but my intel desktop board (an older one) does not have this feature

Comment: xset is for X.org but setterm will work as that uses the terminal emulator itself (backed by console, fbcon, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

This is [DPMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_Display_Power_Management_Signaling) in action. It will turn your monitor off by default after 10 minutes of inactivity. There is command 'xset' which can help you to disable this behavior. You should install it first if you do not have it already.

Try following

```
xset -display :0.0 -dpms
xset -display :0.0 s off
xset -display :0.0 s noblank
```

First one should do the trick. Try other two if first will be not enough.

```
xset q
```

should display current settings. By default it will return (amongst other stuff): DMPS is Enabled. After execution of first commands run xset q again to verify it was disabled. Be inactive for 10 minutes to verify that monitor does not go off.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not running an XServer

Comment: I see. I believe @spuder gave you solution which will work for you in that case.