# How do I disable screen blanking on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium

I am running Raspbian, and I am using this as a display device for a TV in a retail centre. I run Chromium on startup with this line in .profile:

```
xinit /usr/bin/chromium --kiosk --incognito www.mysite.com
```

...however none of the solutions to disable screen blanking seem to work (although they do work if I am in the Raspbian GUI). It is quite important (as you can imagine) that the display screen does not go blank.

Does anyone have any solutions to this?

I have tried the following:

setting the xinitrc file as in this example https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/disable-screen-blanking-in-x-windows-on-raspbian

setting exec /usr/bin/X -s 0 dpms -nolisten tcp "$@" in xserverrc

setting blank timeouts in /etc/kbd/config

setting /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf with the following line: xserver-command=X -s 0 dpms

non of the above have worked

I have noticed a possible solution which entails installing xscreensaver then disabling it but I do not know how to make it run on startup.

Comment: ... Which solutions?

Comment: You can probably edit your answer to include everything you have missed)

Comment: ok, question edited

Comment: Check this [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/629939/how-to-disable-monitor-standby-in-console/629956#629956)

Comment: @Nikolay, that answer does not work either.....

Comment: @coolblue2000, can you post output of `xset -q`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [solution](http://lokir.wordpress.com/2012/09/16/raspberry-pi-kiosk-mode-with-chromium/).
**comment** this line:

```
@xscreensaver -no-splash
```

And add following lines:

```
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
```

Comment: Adding the above xset lines to /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart has worked for me in the past.  I've not had to use the xscreensaver line.

Answer (score 0):

All that is needed to stop the screen from going blank system wide is in `/root/cmdline.txt`. Add:

```
`consoleblank=0`
```

after `console=tty1` and reboot.

Comment: The file's in /boot, not /root

Comment: this is for consoles - not X11 - it' wont help